# getting sql error :Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '904LPUH000614'

Tags: c#

```
public partial class HardwareInformation : BaseForm
{
    string sWhere = "";
    public HardwareInformation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection objConn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.203;Initial Catalog=costing;User ID=sa;Password=Spareage@123");
        if ( searchtextbox.Text.Trim() != "" )
        {
            sWhere = "Where  Srno  '" + searchtextbox.Text;      
        }

        SqlDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select distinct [Srno] ,[Employee Name] ,  [Department] ,  [Thin Client] , [Desktop] , [Lcd] , [Moniter] , [Printer] , [Ups]   from  [dbo].[HardwareDetail] " + sWhere + "", objConn1);
        DataTable objTable = new DataTable();
        objAdapter.Fill(objTable);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = objTable;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 25;
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any single quotation marks in textbox?

Comment: no there is no quatation mark

Comment: Bit of an aside, but: you should really do some sanitisation on the search box text before passing it into the SQL query, otherwise your app is open to SQL injection attacks (assuming this code is going into production).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
"Where Srno = '" + searchtextbox.Text + "'";
```

You forgot `=` sign after `Srno` and close single quotation marks after TextBox text.

In line where SqlDataAdapter is created, in last use

```
 "[Ups] from [dbo].[HardwareDetail] " + sWhere, objConn1);
```

And BTW Please beaware of **SQLInjection.**

Answer (score 1):

There is an = sign missing and an end quote missing after the Textbox text. Thus it should be

```
"Where  Srno = '" + searchtextbox.Text +"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should **never** insert user input directly into your SQL without sanitizing it. You really need to change to a parameterized query:

```
SqlDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select distinct [Srno] ,[Employee Name] ,  [Department] ,  [Thin Client] , [Desktop] , [Lcd] , [Moniter] , [Printer] , [Ups]   from  [dbo].[HardwareDetail] WHERE Srno = @srno", objConn1);

// Change the length and dbtype to match your needs
objAdapter.Parameters.Add("@srno", SqlDbType.NChar, 15, searchtextbox.Text);

DataTable objTable = new DataTable();
objAdapter.Fill(objTable);
```

That saves you from the injection vulnerability, and also removes the need to escape quotes and other special characters.